# Equation for sinusoidal wave with fixed wavelength and amplitude

Tags: graphing-functions, systems-of-equations

I am a programmer. I am writing a program in which I need to show a graph plotted to the user when the user adjusts two sliders, which are the amplitude and wavelength of the wave, say`a` and `w`. I increment `x` each pixel by pixel, now I need a value for `y` in terms of `x` with `a` and `w` constant that would generate the required sinusoidal wave.

```
y = f(x); a, w constants
```

In short, I need an `f(x)` with constant `a` and `w`, that would create a sinusoidal wave with `a` as amplitude and `w` as wavelength. Can anyone help out?

Comment: `y = a * sin( x * 2 * pi / w )` ?

Comment: @Henry You are a life saver!!! Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer. I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y = a * sin( x * 2 * pi / w )` ?